# Number of vertices in a hexagon graph?

Tags: graph-theory

What formula would find the number of vertices within a 'normal' hexagonal graph, based on its radius (number of hexagons from center to edge)?

I've figured with pseudo code:

`for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
   vertices += ((r + i) * 2) + 1;
}
vertices = vertices * 2;`

Given the graph below, with a radius of 2, the above results in:

([((2 + 0) *2) +1] + [((2 + 1) *2) +1]) *2 = 24

[image]

So... Is there a formula that can do this for a radius of n?

Or, given V - F + E = 2, and knowing F = (3* r^2) - (3* r) + 1; a formula to derive the number of edges would work just as well.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Although I can probably guess what you mean by a hexagonal graph, I shouldn't have to guess. Please define exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Casteels - Well, I'm not sure what the correct term is. But I mean that it would consist of normal hexagons, and its overall shape would resemble a hexagon as well. Like the image. Sorry if I'm not explaining it very well.

Comment: Ok so for example, the next "larger" one would be obtained by surrounding your existing image by $12$ hexagons, and then the next larger one would look like the [image here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481528/drawing-hexagon-grid-in-cocos-2d-x)?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A033581

Comment: @Casteels - Yes, exactly.

Comment: @PerryElliott-Iverson - Perfect! thank you. If you post this as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $6n^2$ vertices in such a configuration with $n$ rings of hexagons. See for example, [here](http://oeis.org/A033581).

Comment: The correct link is:   http://oeis.org/A033581